# How to make Windows 8+ show useful info in blue screen?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-10, bsod

Is there any way to make Windows 8 and newer show more info (address, file) when it has blue screen like it was before?

Googling "how to make windows 8 show info in blue screen" or sorts only shows typical questions on how to fix blue screen.

Comment: It's showing the same information it always has, in fact what is display now, actually is more verbose.  In any event there isn't a away to go to the old style of BSOD

Comment: @Ramhound A frowney face with exception name doesn't look like before, when it shown filename and address too.

Comment: The BSOD never showed the file responsible.  In any event it doesn't matter, it can't be changed, and BlueScreenViewer while a great program is natorious for blaming the wrong file for the crash

Comment: @Ramhound This screenshot seems to think otherwise: http://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/x5bsod.png.pagespeed.gp+jp+jw+pj+js+rj+rp+rw+ri+cp+md.ic.vYS2_0xBFt.png
My colleague had often used it to figure out that nvidia driver was the reason and reboot in safe mode afterwards to fix it.

Comment: That is my point the "problem file" isn't identified correctly and that's all BlueScreenViewer detects.

Answer (score 0):

There is free software which allows you to diagnose the problem by viewing the most recent BSOD dump files and telling you what each error code means.

> See [here](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) and download it.